# Comparison of values from file not working in java

Tags: java, string, collections

Currently i am stuck up with a issue regarding comparing values in a text file. Below is my requirement which is a bit unique is what i can say.

I am getting a text file which is having data in the below format. The lines are a series of numbers of a particular format.

223---other line values

354---other line value

756---other line values

754---other line values

854---other line values

923---other line values

I have to validate that all the lines are starting in this order 2,3,7,8,9. There can be multiple lines in between 2 & 9 starting with 2,3,7,7,8,3,7,7,8,9. It is guranteed that 2 and 9 lines will be the first and last lines in the file. Multiple 7's can appear between 3 & 8.

I came up with the logic below for this comparison but the logic works for only one combination of lines starting with 2,3,7,7,8,9.

When there are multiple occurrences of lines like say 2,3,7,7,8,3,7,7,8,9 it does not work. Can someone please help me with what is wrong here and how i can solve this issue. If there is a better option or any other better way for my requirement please suggest so that i can use it. The volume in the input file is not high and can be almost 10 to 20 thousand.

```
 Set<String> recordTypeOrder = new HashSet<>();

 BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new StringReader("path to my file  here"));

 for (String line = rdr.readLine(); line != null; line = rdr.readLine()) {
    if(line.startsWith("2")){
        recordTypeOrder.add("2");

       }else if(line.startsWith("3")){
        recordTypeOrder.add("3");

       }else if(line.startsWith("7")){
        recordTypeOrder.add("7");

       }else if(line.startsWith("8")){
        recordTypeOrder.add("8");

       }else if(line.startsWith("9")){
       recordTypeOrder.add("9");
      }
    }

    Set<String> orderToCompare = new TreeSet<>(recordTypeOrder);
    boolean compare = orderToCompare.equals(actualOrder());
    if(!compare){
        logger.info("== Processing failed =====");
        throw new CustomException("======= Processing failed =======");
    }

  private static Set<String> actualOrder(){

    Set<String> actualOrder= new HashSet<>();
    actualOrder.add("2");
    actualOrder.add("3");
    actualOrder.add("7");
    actualOrder.add("8");
    actualOrder.add("9");
    return actualOrder;
  }
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Why are you using different types of `Sets`? Just use one type.  TreeSet using the AbstractSet::equals method

Comment: Also debug to ensure that the contents are actually the same

Comment: You may look into regular expression also.

Comment: @Shanu Gupta Thanks for your inputs. i have taken your suggestion and implemented using LinkedHashMap and its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store both order and count of `3,7,7,8`. I think `treeset` won't work. Can you try others data structures like `LinkedHashMap`. That way you could just store the data you need in `LinkedHashMap` and then write a custom function to validate it.